# Interview street Median challenge

Tags: java

I was trying to solve the Median challenge at Interviewstreet.com.

I wasn't able to pass most of the test cases. But according to my understanding my code should work fine.

Here is the question:
https://www.interviewstreet.com/challenges/dashboard/#problem/4fcf919f11817

Here is my code:

```
    /* Sample program illustrating input and output */

    import java.util.*;

    class Solution{
public static void main( String args[] ){

     // helpers for input/output        

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int N;
    N = in.nextInt();

    String s[] = new String[N];
    int x[] = new int[N];
    ArrayList<Integer> items=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    float result[]=new float[N];
    //int itemindex=-1;
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        s[i] = in.next();
        x[i] = in.nextInt();

        switch(s[i].charAt(0))
        {

        case 'r':
            if(items.size()<=1)
            {
                result[i]=-1;

            }
            else
            {
                items.remove((Integer)x[i]);
                int itemindex=items.size();
                Collections.sort(items);
                if((itemindex)%2==0)
                {
                    result[i]=(float)         ((items.get((itemindex/2))+items.get(((itemindex)/2)-1))/2.0);


                }
                else
                {
                    result[i]=items.get((itemindex-1)/2);
                }

            }
            break;

        case 'a':
            items.add(x[i]);
            int itemindex=items.size();
            Collections.sort(items);
            if((itemindex)%2==0)
            {
                result[i]=(float)((items.get((itemindex/2))+items.get(((itemindex)/2)-1))/2.0);


            }
            else
            {
                result[i]=items.get((itemindex-1)/2);
            }

            break;



        }

    }

    for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
    {
        if(result[j]==-1)
        {
            System.out.println("Wrong!");
        }
        else
        {
            if((result[j]*10)%10==0)
            {
            System.out.println((int)(result[j]));
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(result[j]);
            }
        }

    }





}
    }
```

I would highly appreciate if someone could help me find out the test cases which will fail  for my code.

Thanks.

Comment: I see that you were redirected here by someone on Stackoverflow.  This question actually belongs there though.  CR is intended for code that the poster believes to be correct.  (Actually, I see that is has 4 close votes on stackoverflow -- that's probably because the question is very broad.  Posting a problem statement, posting a chunk of code, and asking for someone to debug it is a bit of a large task and not really the aim of SO or CR.  Typically when asking a question on SO, you should have already debugged yourself and know a specific question.)

Answer (score 2):

An additional point to the ones mentioned by @palacsint is the check for the object removal:
according to the challenge:

> If the operation is remove and the number x is not in the list, output
>   "Wrong!" in a single line

your code does not check for that: here is what you have:

```
if(items.size()<=1)
            {
              result[i]=-1;
            }
else .....
```

You are marking wrong when the list has a single item or is empty. Obviously this is not what the challenge requires. Therefore, you should discard this "if" block and only check the return value from the remove on the list:

```
boolean ok= items.remove((Integer)x[i]);
if (!ok){
  result[i]=-1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The following is duplicated, you could extract it out a method:

   ```
   int itemindex = items.size();
   Collections.sort(items);
   if (itemindex %2 == 0) {
       result[i]=(float)((items.get((itemindex/2))+items.get(((itemindex)/2)-1))/2.0);
   } else {
       result[i]=items.get((itemindex-1)/2);
   }
   ```
2. `ArrayList<...>` reference types should be simply `List<...>`. See: *Effective Java, 2nd edition*, *Item 52: Refer to objects by their interfaces*

   ```
   List<Integer> items = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   ```

Three bugs:

1. Input:

   ```
   2
   a 214748367
   a 214748365
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   2.14748368E8
   2.14748368E8
   ```
2. Input:

   ```
   2
   a 2147483647
   a 2147483645
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   2147483647
   -2
   ```
3. Processing the output of the following code takes more than the allowed 5 seconds:

   ```
   for (int i = 100000; i > 0; i--) {
       System.out.println("a " + i);
   }
   ```

Some useful reading:

- [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency)
- *Effective Java, 2nd Edition, Item 48: Avoid float and double if exact answers are required*

Comment: +1 you have two important notes so I prefer to add a third point with a comment here instead of giving a partial answer: There is also a mistake in calculating "Wrong!". it is done by checking if the list is empty or has a single item. according to the challenge it should be done if the number is not in the list.

Comment: @A.J.: Thanks! I think you should write it as an answer. I'd upvote it and it would improve our [answer ratio](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review) too.